# Text Highlights as CSS masks?

Tags: css, text, mask, masking

I'm wondering if it's possible to reproduce this text effect:

[image]

It should appear as if the text highlights were reducing the opacity of the images. I guess what you need is a copy of the background layer getting masked in the shapes/positions of the text highlights. But is there a way to really make these masks automatically resize/reposition according to the lines of text? Or any other way to achieve the effect?

This might better explain what I'm after:
[image]

Comment: "This is the site I’m working on..." -* you'd probably want to remove this part to avoid getting accused of spamming

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Sorry.

Comment: it's all good mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for the css property [background-attachment: fixed](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-attachment). This does have the caveat that the background will no longer scroll with the page and remain static, but this way you can guarantee the overlap between the element background and the container background remain the same. There is a fix for the scrolling issue via javascript, for a minor overhead cost, depending on how heavy the graphics are for the browser to render/reposition.

Then you simply apply the same background to the background containing element(.wrap in my case) and the text containing element(wrap in my case) and you get your desired effect as shown in your second image.

Then put the mark in a paragraph element and repeat the text twice. Once in the paragraph, once within the mark.
Then set the paragraph to position relative, and the mark to absolute, so they overlap each other perfectly. This is to counteract the wrap being transparent and not showing the text properly, as the text also becoming transparent.

```css
.wrap, .wrap mark {
   background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/hAodNjT.jpg');
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
.wrap p {
  position: relative;
}
.wrap mark {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   opacity: 0.4;
}
img {
   width: 300px;
   height: auto;
}
.wrap {
   padding-top:160px;
   position: relative;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
}
.wrap img {
   position:absolute;
   top:60px;
   
   z-index:0;
}
.wrap p {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cULI8TG.png">
  <p>some text that runs over the image<mark>some text that runs over the image</mark></p>
  <p>some other text that runs over the image<mark>some other text that runs over the image</mark></p>
</div>
```

with a background scroll fix, does introduce more overhead when scrolling

```js
var $affected = $('.wrap, .wrap mark');
let handler = (e) => {
    $affected.css({'background-position' : '-'+window.scrollX+'px -'+window.scrollY+'px'});
}
$(window).on('resize scroll', handler);
```

```css
.wrap, .wrap mark {
   background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/hAodNjT.jpg');
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
.wrap p {
  position: relative;
}
.wrap mark {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   opacity: 0.4;
}
img {
   width: 300px;
   height: auto;
}
.wrap {
   padding-top:160px;
   position: relative;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
}
.wrap img {
   position:absolute;
   top:60px;
   
   z-index:0;
}
.wrap p {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/cULI8TG.png">
  <p>some text that runs over the image<mark>some text that runs over the image</mark></p>
  <p>some other text that runs over the image<mark>some other text that runs over the image</mark></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow! That's exactly what I was looking for, and so much easier than I thought. I have to read up on how to embed custom CSS in Webflow though, hope it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: @KT9000 I also added a fix for if you need the background to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mark` tag of HTML using background color with opacity:

```css
/*custom styling of higlihter*/
mark{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.38);
    color: black;
}
.wrap{
background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/color-splash-series-background-design-260nw-587409425.jpg");
height: 230px;
width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
Do <mark>not forget to buy milk today</mark>
<div>
```

Note: the mark tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

Another solution, using `background` and `color` on `<p>` tag with `gradient`:

```css
.wrap{
 background: grey;
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 background:url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/halloween-background-full-moon-creepy-house-flying-bats-halloween-background-full-moon-creepy-house-125024932.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
}
p{
font-size:20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff00, #000000c9 , #ffffff00);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><p>Don't play with<p></div>
```

You can change the color accordingly.

[Reference](https://gomakethings.com/highlighting-effect-with-css/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's not quite enough to solve my problem though. I've added another image to my original post for better explanation. Thing is the highlights should be "invisible" on the checkerboard background (that's actually my background, not an alphachannel) where there's nothing between the text and the background.

Comment: @KT9000 you can use background color with transparency to achieve this i;ll update my code with pic behind for better understanding

Comment: @KT9000 Updated my ans using gradiant and background color hope that helps do let me know if you still got and issue, You can change opacity and % of color that covers the area in second solution

Comment: I've updated my mockup, unfortunately gradients are not an option because there are multiple images with transparencies moving behind the text. Also, I cannot use a plain color for the highlights because I want them to display the background image/pattern.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort! Looks like there is the perfect solution right in CSS, so I was thinking too complicated instead of just looking up all the available background properties.

Comment: Oh my bad i am not getting that right Sorry for misunderstood :( Tschallacka solution worked for you Glad to head that !